# What is the purpose of %s, %tc, %Tc?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I was studying a program about getting dates, time and then after browsing online I see this one:

```
System.out.printf("The date is %s\n", new Date() );

System.out.printf("The date is %tc\n", new Date() );

System.out.printf("The DATE is %Tc\n", new Date() );
```

which seems to be straightforward but I want to understand the use of %s, %tc, %Tc here.

Comment: [The documentation of `printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) guides us to [*Date/Time conversions* section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt).

Comment: See documentation of [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) class. Regarding `%tc` and `%Tc` search for Date/Time Conversions

Answer (score 1):

These are special characters that are being used to format a date.
Here is a good example for this:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/UnixdateformattcTc.htm

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.printf("Unix date format: %tc/%Tc\n", now, now);
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
Unix date format: Thu May 24 15:58:29 PDT 2007/THU MAY 24 15:58:29 PDT 2007
```

All credits to this page

Comment: Note: more then Unix time is "Internet time", as required on email and other internet protocols (which usually predates implementation in Unix).